# Is there a way to computed again class variable when create class?

Tags: python

I have some classes as below

```py
from random import randint

class A:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

class B:
    var_1 = A('a', randint(10, 20))
```

I want to every create instance from `class B`, `var_1` have different value.

ex:

```py
B().var_1.value != B().var_1.value
```

I know that if I move `var_1` from `class variable` to `instance variable` I will have different.

Comment: "I want to every create instance from class B, var_1 have different value." Then use an instance variable. That is what they are for.

Comment: "I know that if I move var_1 from class variable to instance variable I will have different." That's the answer to your own question, isn't it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, No `var_1` still a class variable

Comment: So why not make it an instance variable, if that will do what you want?

Comment: @kaya3, No I want to still using `var_1` as a class variable not a instance variable

Comment: Why? That's like saying "I want a blue car, but I want it to be red, but still blue."

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `var_1` to an instance variable for your requirement that different instances of class `B` have different values stored in `var_1`. A class variable's value is by definition shared between instances, which isn't what you want.

Here is a modified version of your program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class A:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

class B:
    __value = 0
    def __init__(self):
        B.__value += 1
        self.var_1 = A('a', B.__value)

print(B().var_1.value != B().var_1.value)
```

It always prints `True`.

Each time B is instantiated, its class variable `__value` is incremented by `1`, and its value is stored in the instance variable `var_1`. This guarantees that the value is always different, as opposed to your code where there is a chance that two instances share the same number since the value is randomly generated.